# Keyboard input in web-component-tester not working

Tags: polymer, web-component-tester

I'm trying to test our polymer component which has an iron-input in it. To test things like max-length and filtering of allowed patterns I would like to test for certain keyboard inputs.
Somehow this does not seem to work, the value of the iron-input element stays the same.

I tried these methods:

```
// from iron-test-helpers
MockInteractions.pressAndReleaseKeyOn(input, undefined, [], '2');

// generic way
var e = document.createEvent('TextEvent');
e.initTextEvent('textInput', true, true, null, 'Bob');
input.dispatchEvent(e);

//check input.value (native) and input.bindValue (iron-input var, set after input event is triggered)
console.log(input.value);

console.log(input.bindValue);
assert.equal(input.bindValue, '123456');
```